# rails - can onclick work with a method as well as javascript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I use the following line to set up an onchange action pointing to a javascript function, it seems to work.

```
<% @documents.each do |document| %>
  <td>< %= check_box_tag "document_ids[]", document.id, checked_flag,
  :onchange =>  "myFunction(#{document.id})"   %></td>
```

However, if I try to point to a def/method, it does not work as expected. It appears that the method is called as each line is displayed. I thought that the onchange/onclick only called the action if there was a change or click.

```
<td><%= check_box_tag "document_ids[]", document.id, checked_flag, {:onchange =>  handle_checkboxes(document.id,checked_flag)}   %></td>
```

Does Ruby/Rails allow you to call a method with `onchange/onclick` with a `checkbox_tag`?

My goal is to build an array that I can use in a find to just show the documents that were checked.

```
def handle_checkboxes(id,flag)
  $doc_ids.push(id.to_s)
  $test2[id] = 'push'
  $test3 = 'We arrived'
end
```

If I use the `checkbox_tag` with the method the variables look like

> $doc_ids.inspect["9999999", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29"]
>
> $test2.inspect ["initial", nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, "push", "push", "push", "push", "push", "push", "push", "push", "push"]

but nothing seems to change if I click on some of the checkboxes.

Comment: For javascript (client) to run ruby code (server)  you need to call the server with a request.

Answer (score 3):

I think this question lacks some serious concept knowledge. `onchange` is triggered on the client side, 'in the browser'. You can't have a callback function placed in your server to be triggered for that event. You should be having a JavaScript function which does an ajax call to do what you intend to do on your server side.

Edit : All your Ruby code in the page gets executed in your server and the resulting html and js are the only ones sent to the browser.